# [Blender 2.8]Why autosave do not save edit-mode data, and how can I auto save them?

Tags: edit-mode

In Blender 2.8, autosave said that edit-mode data won't be saved, and I just noticed this after an hour's work lost.
So any way to force Blender to save data in edit-mode when autosaving?